# Jupyter Notebook wont output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My simple program is supposed to output 1,2,3,4,5,6, but when executed, it just skips to the next cell.  I ran a for loop, where the output was displayed.

Looking for any pointers on how to consistently get an output.

```
def main():
    x = 0

    while (x<6):
        print (x)
    x = x +1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: did you call the `main()` function?

Comment: Your posted code contains an infinite loop that prints `0` on each iteration, because your increment is outside the loop: that line needs to be indented.  Also, your code merely defines a function and quits without executing that function.  This may be your problem.

Comment: What happens when you put this code (with corrected indentation) directly in a cell, rather than in a function?

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be inside the while loop. What's happening is that your kernel is getting locked up by that infinite loop (since you never actually increment `x`)

```
def main():
    x = 0

    while (x<6):
        print (x)
        x = x +1
```

---

```
main()
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I have added the corrects, and I am still not getting the output. When the code is ran, my cursor just goes to the next cell.

Comment: Are you calling the function? You need to put main() in the same cell if you want that to happen.

Comment: I added two lines at bottom that made it compile. Thank you for the help. I am learning python after using c++ in college. 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Comment: That doesn't make sense, to be honest. If you are using a jupyter notebook, you just have to call the function in any cell after defining it. You don't need if __name__ == "__main__": inside jupyter.